# I cannot display a javascript variable to a <p>?

Tags: javascript

I don't know what is wrong with my code I had reference with some of my codes and done this but i cannot display a variable to a pharagraph?

this is my code on script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myId = document.getElementById('myId').value; // 
    var scope = 'global';

    function testScope() { 

    var scope = 'local';

        function innerFunc() {  
        return scope;           
        }                           

    return innerFunc(); 
    }

    var answer = testScope(); 

    myId.innerHTML = answer;
</script>
```

on html

```
<p id="myId"><!-- no variable displayed --></p>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: A `<p>` element does not have a "value" property.

Comment: And if it did, the `value` property's value wouldn't have an `innerHTML` property. Nor would it be an ID, presumably, so `myId` seems an odd name for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById('myId')` instead of `document.getElementById('myId').value`. Because `<p>` element hasn't `value` property

```js
function checkFunctionScope() {
  var myId = document.getElementById('myId');
  var scope = 'global';

  function testScope() {

    var scope = 'local';

    function innerFunc() {
      return scope;
    }

    return innerFunc();
  }

  var answer = testScope();

  myId.innerHTML = answer;
}

window.onload = checkFunctionScope;
```

```html
<p id="myId">
  <!-- no variable displayed -->
</p>
```

Comment: didn't notice it, was following beginner course in pluralsight and the some sample is with .value, i didnt know, anyway can you suggest me a javascript learning path? do you know which best course to take? i just started learning javascript

Comment: I still dont know why my browser doesn't show local i did copy your code, but it is in console,

Comment: @GlendonPhilippBaculio I updated my code, check it now

Comment: why did you use onload?

Comment: @GlendonPhilippBaculio `checkFunctionScope` is the handler function to be called when the window's load event fires. That means, `checkFunctionScope` is called when the window is completed loading, otherwise your `<p>` element is completed loading.  See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: hmm yeah that was what i was missing, thanks, i tried many codes but not that